# Java + Selenium = Store text into a var

Tags: java, selenium, copy, paste

I need to generate a number through a website and store it into a var. So I will use this var later in my test to fill a registration form.

But I'm not able to get the value generated by this with 'gettext' and 'getattribute'. I tried to simulate a 'ctrl+c' but I don't know how to store the 'ctrl+v' value into a var as well.

Could you help?

This is the website (to generate fake brazil id number) you just need to generate the number by pressing "Gerar CPF". But the number generated isn't displayed in firepath or in the html page source.

http://www.geradordecpf.org/

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using java then try--  if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('numero').value");
}

Comment: And how do I associate a var to it? I need a var (string) to receive this value

Comment: Try simpler--        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/HTML5TestApp/prod.html");
        Object val = js.executeScript("document.getElementById('numero').value;");
        System.out.println(val);

Comment: @SIslam Please don't post answers as comments. If you have the answer, post it as a comment... and you don't need to use the JSE to do this.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to retrieve a value in a text box. So you cannot retrieve the typed value from a text field using a getText method.

You will be able to get the value of the text field using getAttribute value method.

```
WebElement text_field_element = driver.findElement(By.Id("numero"));
String value = text_field_element.getAttribute("value")
```

We have faced same kind of issue before and above method saved us. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

The reason you can't read out that Number is because it's been created via JS. It is not actually part of the HTML Element.

Why do you have to generate the Number trough the Website? 
If you generate the Number via Java it'd do it.

PS: If it's because the Number is generated in a specific way, just copy it from here: http://www.geradordecpf.org/assets/js/main.js

All it does is generate Numbers. Any Language / Script can do that :)

Comment: I just have to copy and paste in a new java class? Sorry, I'm really new in Java.

Comment: If you are that new to Java, you should be reading tutorials and the Java docs.